# useEffect() vs setTimeout() for side effects

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a general question about **useEffect()** vs **setTimeout()**.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => console.log(count)); // effect

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    setTimeout(() => console.log(count), 5000); // log to console after 5 seconds
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Counter;
```

In the above code,

```
setCount(count + 1);
setTimeout(() => console.log(count), 5000);
```

using `setTimeout()`, I am trying to log `count` after 5 seconds, by which time `setCount()`, although asynchronous, would have definitely finished.

Then why does that still print the previous value of `count`, while `useEffect()` code prints the updated value? Can someone tell me what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of things to say about this code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => console.log(count), [count]); // Add the dependencies array, the callback of use effect will be call only if a dependency is updated

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCount((count) => count + 1); // Use a callback which takes as argument the previous state, because if you click multiple times on the button, as setCount is asynchronous, it won't add 1 for each click
    setTimeout(() => console.log(count), 5000); // log to console after 5 seconds
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Counter;
```

I think that it is because the callback of setTimeout is evaluated before the njew count variable is computed, so it logs the previous value, where useEffect's callback is called when a dependency is updated, so when you increment count.